# [iPhone]How to customize header of Section in grouped TableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, grouped-table

To customize cell, we implement class inherit UITableViewCell. Now, to customize header of Section in grouped UITableView (same to below picture), how to do? Please guide to me!
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Implement `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` in your table view delegate.

Answer (score 6):

Starting with iOS 5 you also need to implement

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

In addition to

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Otherwise it won't work.

From [Apple's reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

*The returned object can be a UILabel or UIImageView object, as well as a custom view. This method only works correctly when tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: is also implemented.*